# Arduino Networking protocol

Tags: arduino, protocols, network-protocols

I am designing an application on which an arduino board communicates with a server. I understand the first thing i need to do is to design a protocol , but am not really sure on how to go about it. The description of the functionality is shown below

> Arduino will communicate with the server. When an RFID tag is placed
>   on the arduino, the Arduino must immediately initiate communication
>   with the server, this will be done so as for the server to open its
>   database , search for the given tag, and then classify it according to
>   the priviledges within the server. i.e it will search through the
>   tables within the database for the given tag, and when found, it must
>   Identify the table from which the tag exists and give necessary
>   permissions to the arduino. The server will then send a response to
>   the arduino board which then closes connection. so i have come up with
>   the protocol as

```
 1)Initiation of communication
 2)If Communication is successful,
 arduino sends the received tag to the server and if  not a signal is
 shown on the arduino to state that connection was not feasible.
 3)Server receives the tag, and uses it to verify priviledges and then
  sends a yes or no to the arduino 
  4)Arduino closes communication
```

I am not sure if i can conclude this to be my protocol or in protocol design i need further refinement. Any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: Never design a protocol. There are thousands already available.

Comment: Did you design a new communication method? First, look at [OSI layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and try to figure where to place your requirements. Then check existing protocols. And if you didn't find nothing appropriate, proceed to your own protocol - always keeping in mind its place in OSI model.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of link arduino is using to communicate with server? If you are using a serial link then you can have your light weight protocol which is fine. But if you communicating over ethernet or bluetooth, then they have their own stack based on osi model. You will need to put your part on application layer most probably.

Comment: @praks411 the ardiuno uses ethernet shield hence ethernet is the communication method

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use Above System architecture for for your development you can used MFRC512 module for read information from RFID and process it using arduino and passed it to server or cloud. you can used arduino ethernet shield or wifi interface to communicate with your server. i think this will help you.